# Retrieve a post's featured image with PHP outside of WordPress

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a little Windows application that I would like to be able to use featured images from posts on my site with.

My site lists and reviews modifications for a computer game and the application installs those modifications.  Think of it as a very basic Steam, for those that know what Steam is.

When a user installs a modification from a file on my site, I would like the application to visit the site, search for the file and then use the featured image within the application.

I understand most of that is outside the scope of this thread, but is there a way to find the URL of the image using PHP but outside of WordPress?

Perhaps from the post ID.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to achieve those features is to implement some sort of interface, usually in JSON or XML.

To do this, you either use a plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ <= Will probably part of core in WP 4.0) or do the AJAX function yourself.

An example would be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_thumbnail', 'ajax_get_thumbnail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_thumbnail', 'ajax_get_thumbnail' );
function ajax_get_thumbnail() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'post-thumbnail' );

    echo json_encode($thumb);

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

The call for that action would be: `http://www.yourwebhost.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_thumbnail&post_id=15`

Please mind, that the 15 is just an example. You would get a json object in return, that contains witdh, height and the url to the post thumbnail.